How to modify legend symbol for geom_text using key_glyph?
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars)))
p + geom_text(aes(colour = factor(cyl)))


But I want another symbol (let's say another letter or an arithmetic symbol) instead of an 'a' to be shown in the legend. How should I use key_glyph to get it?
Thanks!

You could in theory go the key_glyph route with a custom key drawing function, but there is an easier way.
The label is an aesthetic, so you'd override it using guide_legend(override.aes).
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg, label = rownames(mtcars))) + 
  geom_text(aes(colour = factor(cyl))) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(label = "X")))


Created on 2024-07-07 with reprex v2.1.0
